# Excel vba code to read outlook email from inbox from bottom

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of below coding I am able to retrieve the data from outlook inbox and update the same in excel. 
The problem is that I am not able to update the latest response as macro read first come first update basis. If I get the response from abc yesterday and updated response from abc today, the macro is updating the yesterday's response. How can we change the code so that macro should read the emails from bottom of folder and the data that is pulled is updated.

In short, I want to update the latest response in my records.

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application, oOutlook As Object
Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder, oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strAddress As String, strEntryId As String, getSmtpMailAddress As String
Dim objAddressentry As Outlook.AddressEntry, objExchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem, objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oOutlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oInbox = oOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oMail In oInbox.Items

    If oMail.SenderEmailType = "SMTP" Then
        strAddress = oMail.SenderEmailAddress

    Else
        Set objReply = oMail.Reply()
        Set objRecipient = objReply.Recipients.Item(1)
        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID
        objReply.Close OlInspectorClose.olDiscard
        strEntryId = objRecipient.EntryID
        Set objAddressentry = oOutlook.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryId)
        Set objExchangeUser = objAddressentry.GetExchangeUser()
        strAddress = objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()
    End If

    getSmtpMailAddress = strAddress
    body = oMail.body
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop backwards:

```
    For i = oInbox.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeName(oInbox.item(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            Set oMail = oInbox.item(i)
            'Do stuff here
            Set oMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next i
```